# Avoid glare on facade/architectural lighting

Tags: lighting, outdoor

I have a neighboring house that is lit with flood lights from all four corners, and am trying to design some form of shielding to eliminate stray lighting and glare from this lighting setup, which is leaking to the neighboring properties, including mine. Dark Yellow is light required for facade lighting, light yellow is stray light hitting everything else
[image: Dark Yellow is light required for facade lighting, light yellow is stray light hitting everything else]

What I need is to design some form of panel that eliminates stray lights AND reflections in both directions. I have come up with this but it doesn't really work as intended:
[image: The funnel prohibits direct light, but creates a reflection from the panels themselves]
The funnel prohibits direct light, but creates a reflection from the panels themselves

Making the funnel block direct AND incident light is beyond me without making the panels perfect within a millimetre, and I believe there must be a better way to handle this...

Edit: affected neighbors

Comment: Would the owners/occupants of this house be amenable to reducing the luminance of the bulbs and/or using more tightly focused bulbs and/or changing the pointing angle to be more parallel to their walls?

Comment: Angle, probably, distance and/or positioning along the axis probably not. I'll amend the question to point out that this house is positioned on a corner lot to make it even harder to solve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have devised a solution that doesn't involve creating a "snout" that is attached to the light source themselves: the issue will always be that any attached plate will reflect light at the angle of incidence , and that light will mostly be reflected in the direction the second plate tries to block, and this is a suboptimal solution.

What I realized, however, is that a plate that is disconnected from the light source itself, either via metal rods or attached to the ground some other place, can be positioned as a direct barrier in the path of the unwanted light, and any reflection will be back towards the light itself. [image]

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is a focal point. Focal points, as you probably realize, are adjusted with convex/concave lenses.

The lights you're talking about are being used beyond their focal point, they need to be focused with a lense, set closer to the house, and/or need to be upgraded to extreme wattage.

Not sure you can get there from where you're starting.